# I want to get all the returns in real time from a script that sends several lines of information in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js

That is the problem I need to get all the outputs of a script that I run from node js and get all of them, now I get them but only when the script process is completely finished and I want to get them every time it sends them.
This is the code:

```
    exec(line, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            out = "!!!!!!! ERROR EN ComandLine (" + Today() + ")-------!! : \n " + error.message;
            console.log(_out);
            WriteLog(_out);
            socket.send("ERROR");
            return;
        }
        //Standar error
        if (stderr) {
            out = "!!!!!!! STDERROR EN ComandLine (" + Today() + ") : \n " + stderr.message
            console.log(_out);
            WriteLog(_out);
            socket.send("ERROR");
            return;
        }
        //resultado final

        if (stdout.toString().includes("Se fini")) {
            console.log("Server end task");
            _generating = false;
        }
        _out = "------- STD OUT ------- (" + Today() + ") : \n " + stdout.message;
        console.log(_out);
        WriteLog(_out);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are using `child_process.exec`. For your use case `child_process.spawn` would be the right choice I think since it is emitting events you can listen to.

See the nodejs doc https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Something like this should roughly implement the behavior you are looking for.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const cmd = spawn(line);

cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  _out = "------- STD OUT ------- (" + Today() + ") : \n " + data;
  console.log(_out);
  WriteLog(_out);
});

cmd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  _out = "!!!!!!! STDERROR EN ComandLine (" + Today() + ") : \n " + data
  console.log(_out);
  WriteLog(_out);
  socket.send("ERROR");
  return;
});

cmd.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log("Server end task");
  _generating = false;
});
```

Comment: Ye it works but not for me, I execute a websocket and i cant land this command but without the webshocket it works perfectly if u have some idea